# slideshow of images and keeping a text on it all the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I have to make a slideshow of images based on my this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/50kah1q0/8/). I need to have three more images just after this [image](https://s4.postimg.org/yg8mjvsv1/image-home.png) which is already there in my jsfiddle. So I will have three more images and three dots at the bottom border of the image and if I click those dots, it should show other image and I want to keep `BESPOKE INSURANCE SOLUTIONS` text on top of my slideshow.

I tried integrating this [w3schools example](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_slideshow_dots2) but my original jsfiddle is getting messed up and it is not working at all. Here is my [updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/50kah1q0/9/) and as you can see it is messed up. What is the best way to solve this?

Below is my code:

```
<div class="header">
      <div class="header-background">
          <img src="https://s4.postimg.org/yg8mjvsv1/image-home.png">
     </div> 

         <div class="orange-bar">
            <img class="orange-bar-image" src="https://s12.postimg.org/dmd7nd1dp/headline.png">
        </div>

        <div class="topnav">
             <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li class="home"><img src="https://s11.postimg.org/ywuxj79j7/logo.png" style="width:240px; height:53px;"></li>

                </ul>

            </nav>
        </div>
        <h1 class="text-inside-orange">BESPOKE INSURANCE SOLUTIONS</h1>
    </div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.header {
    position: relative;
    height: 769px;
}
.header-background {
    height: 769px;
    width: 100%;
}
.orange-bar {
    position: relative;
    top: -430px;
    left: -160px;
}
.topnav {
    position: relative;
    top: -890px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    height: 89px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #EF7440;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.topnav ul>li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
}
li.home {
    position: relative;
    right: 40px;
}
li.insurance {
    margin-right: 80px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    left: 15px;
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    font-family: AvantGarde;
    letter-spacing: .30em;
}
li.login-signup {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 10px;
    position: relative;
    left: 20px;
    top: 5px;
    font-family: Adelle PE;
    letter-spacing: .30em;
    color: white;
}
li.get-covered {
    border-color: #EF7440;
    border-style: solid;
    color: white;
    top: 3px;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
    left: 35px;
    letter-spacing: .30em;
    font-family: Adelle PE;
}
li.get-covered {
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 10px !important;
    padding-top: 10px !important;
}
li.login-signup {
    padding-top: 30px !important;
    position: relative;
    left: -35px;
}
li.insurance {
    padding-top: 30px !important;
}
body {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.header h1 {
    padding-left: 110px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    left: -175px;
    letter-spacing: .300em;
    position: relative;
    top: -613px;
    font-family: "AvantGarde";
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: What javascript have you tried?

Answer (score -1):

This is my way. You should create a div contain BESPOKE INSURANCE SOLUTIONS, set position: absolute, align: top left. It's keep text no changes.